# Query optimization - indexing

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, data-warehouse

I use the following script for inserting data into a SQL Server table.

All the columns from `TempCdbSap` are `nvarchar`, this means all the join are made with nvarchar columns. `Amount` columns also needs a convertion to `decimal`.

I also have a nonclustered index on `TempCdbSap` for column `Consolidation`
which includes:

```
[Year], [Month], [Branch], [CostCenter], [CostCategorySAP], [Amount]
```

The query will return/insert ~ 8 mil rows.

Could anyone suggest some optimization on this?

```
insert into FactTable (...)
   select distinct 
       da.ID_Date as [ID_Date] ,
       sc.Pk_Scenario as [ID_Scenario],
       co.Pk_Consolidation as [ID_Consolidation],
       br.PK_ShareBranch as [Id_Branch],
       ka.PK_Cost as [ID_CostCategory],
       cc.Pk_CostCenter as [ID_CostCenter],
       isnull(case ka.AccountType
                when 'c' then -1*cast(replace (amount,',','.') as decimal(18,2))
                when 'r' then 1*cast(replace (amount,',','.') as decimal(18,2)) 
                when 's' then  cast(replace (amount,',','.') as decimal(18,2))
              end, 0)  as Amount,
       isnull(case ka.AccountType
                when 'c' then -1*cast(replace (amount,',','.') as decimal(18,2))
                when 'r' then 1*cast(replace (amount,',','.') as decimal(18,2)) 
                when 's' then  cast(replace (amount,',','.') as decimal(18,2))
              end, 0) as SharedAmount,
       cy.Pk_Currency as ID_Currency
   from 
       [dbo].[TempCdbSap] cdb
   inner join 
       DimBranchShare br on br.[Branch No] = cdb.branch
   inner join 
       DimDate da on da.MonthName = cdb.[Month] and da.Year = cdb.[year]
   inner join 
       DimCostCenter cc on cc.CostCenterName = cdb.CostCenter
   inner join  
       DimScenario sc on sc.ScenarioTypeDEU = cdb.Scenario
   inner join 
       DimConsolidation co on co.ConsolidationType = cdb.Consolidation
   inner join 
       DimCostCategory ka on ka.AccountNo = cdb.CostCategorySAP
   inner join 
       DimCurrency cy on cy.CurrencyCode = cdb.Currency
   where
       da.ID_Date >= year(br.RowStartDate) * 100 + month(br.RowStartDate) 
       and da.ID_Date < year(br.RowEndDate) * 100 + month(br.RowEndDate)
```

**UPDATE:**

The execution plan is:

[image]

Comment: You should include your rdbms name and provide an explain / analyze report

Comment: Hi @JuanCarlosOropeza!  The execution plan for the SQL Query was also added.

Comment: It seems you need to create indexes on each column used in `JOIN` clauses

Comment: @DmitryPolyakov Could be a columnstore index on TempCdbSap also a good idea?

Comment: Your main problem are implicit data-type conversions. No index would help here. I would recommend you to insert data from `TempCdbSap` to temporary table with proper types. Then you can add indexes to this temporary table.

Comment: It really requires the execution plan. However, as all of the joins are inner joins, the first thing is to find out which dimension removes the larger number of records from table cdb. Join that dimension to your cbd table and store the result in another temp table, say temp2. Temp2 should have numerical fields. Build indices on temp2 and then join it to other tables.